# Cordova Google Maps Geocode's default location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3, cordova-plugins

Is there a way to set default location (like 'San Francisco') for this plugin?

https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/Geocoder

I tried this and it doesn't work:

`plugin.google.maps.Geocoder.geocode({'address':'550 1st', 'location': 'San Francisco'}, function...);`

**Goal**

I want to do something like jQuery Geocomplete: http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/

But I can set default location of the specific city: http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/location.html

**UPDATE 1**

I tried this based on answer below and didn't work either. It should return me a list of addresses in Seattle.

```
function aaa(str) {
  var directionsDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
  var seattle = new google.maps.LatLng(47.6097, -122.3331);
  var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 7,
  center: seattle
  };

  plugin.google.maps.Geocoder.geocode({'address': str}, function(results) {
    if (results.length) {
      var result = results[0];
      var position = result.position; 
      console.log(results);
    } else {
      console.log("Not found");
    }
  });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I think it works as it worked for me.

```
var directionsDisplay;
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
            var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(18.9750, 72.8258);
            var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: mumbai
            };
```

Comment: Is this Javascript version of Google Maps or Cordova version?

Comment: It is Java Script version.. but I am using this in my cordova app and it works fine.

Comment: Hmm I may be able to just use this http://plnkr.co/edit/Qw0zE4hHQOf2tYqcKEiB?p=preview